# Вывести текст ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Всем привет! Возможно глупый вопрос, но все же нужен ответ или понять, что не так.. Как вывести текст на ReactJS, чтобы потом я мог вызвать его так {sometext}?

Добавил код, вот там где meta description - нужно вывести текст.

```js
render() {
    const {meta, magazine, tag: {title}, posts: {count, items}, regionCode} = this.props;
    const {visible} = this.state;

    return (
        <div>
            {meta &&
                <Helmet>
                    {meta.title ? <title>{meta.title}</title> : <title>{title}</title>}
                    {meta.description ? <meta name="description" content="Место для дескрипшена"/> : <meta name="description" content={sometext += title}/>}
                    <meta property="og:url" content={typeof window === 'undefined' ? null : window.location.href}/>
                </Helmet>
            }
            <ListPageHeader title={`#${title}`} subtitle={this.getCountTitle()}/>
            {count === 0 ? (
                <EmptyResult hideSubtitle title={<FormattedMessage id="tagPage.emptyTitle"/>}/>
            ) : (
                <CardsList
                    items={items.slice(0, visible)}
                    hasMore={count > items.length}
                    handleMoreClick={this.handleMoreClick}
                />
            )}
            {regionCode === 'en' ? null : <RecentIssue {...magazine}/>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: `{'sometext'}`? Т.е. не переменную, а просто статичный текст? А что у вас есть? Пример кода?

Comment: @mrEvgenX добавил код!